# Trying to understand Gaussian Process

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process

I'm reading the GPML book and in [Chapter 2 (page 15)](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW2.pdf), it tells how to do regression using Gaussian Process(GP), but I'm having a hard time figuring how it works.

In Bayesian inference for parametric models, we first choose a prior on the model parameters $\theta$, that is $p(\theta)$; second, given the training data $D$, we compute the likelihood $p(D|\theta)$; and finally we have the posterior of $\theta$ as $p(\theta|D)$, which will be used in the *predictive distribution* $$p(y^*|x^*,D)=\int p(y^*|x^*,\theta)p(\theta|D)d\theta$$, and the above is what we do in Bayesian inference for parametric models, right?

Well, as said in the book, GP is non-parametric, and so far as I understand it, after specifying the *mean function* $m(x)$ and the *covariance function* $k(x,x')$, we have a GP over function $f$, $$f \sim GP(m,k)$$, and this is the **prior** of $f$. Now I have a **noise-free** training data set $$D=\{(x_1,f_1),...,(x_n,f_n)\}$$， I thought I should compute the **likelihood** $p(D|f)$ and then the **posterior** $p(f|D)$, and finally use the posterior to make predictions.

HOWEVER, that's not what the book does! I mean, after specifying the prior $p(f)$, it doesn't compute the likelihood and posterior, but just go straight forward to the predictive prediction.

Question:

1) Why not compute the likelihood and posterior? Just because GP is non-parametric, so we don't do that?

2) As what is done in the book (page 15~16), it derives the **predictive distribution** via the joint distribution of training data set $\textbf f$ and test data set $\textbf f^*$, which is termed as **joint prior**. Alright, this confuses me badly, why joint them together?

3) I saw some articles call $f$ the **latent** variable, why?

Comment: Personally, I don't think GP regression belongs to Bayesian inference, since it doesn't follow the steps in Bayesian approach. The so-called predictive distribution in GP is derived by jointing the training and test data **in the prior**, and then conditioning on the training data, it doesn't make use of likelihood or posterior.

Answer (score 2):

> and the above is what we do in Bayesian inference for parametric
>   models, right?

The book is using Bayesian model averaging, which is the same for parametric models or any other Bayesian method, given that you have posterior over your parameters.

> Now I have a noise-free training data set

It doesn't need to be 'noise-free'. See later pages.

> HOWEVER, that's not what the book does! I mean, after specifying the
>   prior p(f), it doesn't compute the likelihood and posterior, but just
>   go straight forward to the predictive prediction.

See this: https://people.cs.umass.edu/~wallach/talks/gp_intro.pdf

I believe, in page 17 we have the prior, and later the likelihood. I believe if you write the derivations, and find the posterior, and then average over the posterior for prediction (like in the weight-space view) it will result in the same equations as in page 19 for mean and covariance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I've already seen that many books don't mention Bayesian at all, they just compute the conditional distribution $p(f^*|f)$, and say this is the posterior, what the hell?

Comment: Finding the conditional is basically using the Bayes formula. Writing stuff in the conventional Bayesian formulation is a little cumbersome for GPs; they just  refer to finding the conditional and ....

Comment: AFAIK, the conditional is computed this way, $p(x|y)=p(x,y)/p(y)$, but Bayes formula is $p(x|y)=p(y|x)p(x)/p(y)$. I don't see why finding conditional is using Bayes formula, could you please be more specific?

Comment: And as you said in the comment, "writing stuff in the conventional Bayesian formulation is cumbersome for GPs", by *conventional Bayesian formulation*, did you mean, first compute the posterior $p(f|D)$, then compute the predictive distribution $p(f^*|D)=\int p(f^*|f)p(f|D)df$.